# why the time() in this hosting provider is out of phase? php

Tags: php, hosting

Ok the php version  is 7.3.16

Thecnical support answered me to change the server time in the hosting panel

```
Its set to **America/La_Paz** Im in La Paz.
```

when I execute the php funcion `time()` It retrieves a time about 40 seconds out of phase.

When I check the timezones in timezoneconverter.com

It is out of phase 40 seconds too.....how can I fix this?

The hour is ok. the problem is a small variation of seconds (about 40)

for example here is

```
08:56:03
```

after using `time()`

it retrieves

```
08:55:21
```

Comment: This is more of a server issue. If you don't have access to run ntpdate, then you'll need to contact your hosting provider to let them know that the server time is out of sync.

Comment: Server is out of sync with What?

Comment: comparing with the google time.

Comment: I would assume that it's out of sync with the atomic clock. For most servers, it's not a big issue. It really only becomes an issue when it's several minutes out of sync, or if you're running services that are extremely time-based, such as multi-factor authentication.